# Is there anyway to keep chart label across

Tags: chart.js

I am implementing chartjs, when the number of col too large. It will display like this:

[image]

My question is: Is there any way to keep the label always across?

For example:

[image]
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify `maxRotation` (and `minRotation`) in the [`tick` configuration](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/#tick-configuration). Be aware that Chart.js may omit labels to ensure the text does not overlap.

```
options: {
  scales: {
    xAxes: [{
      ticks: {
        maxRotation: 0
      }
    }]
  }
}
```

Comment: @timcluton: thanks you so much. Its exactly resolve my problem!